# How to make KDE menu (in CentOS) take new .desktop file into account?

Tags: centos, kde

My program's installer creates .desktop files into `~/Desktop` and `~/.local/share/applications`. In most Linuxes this is enough to create respective menu item and desktop icon.

In CentOS 7 with KDE, the items don't appear. I found a manual workaround:right-click on start-button => Edit applications => Save. This seems to refresh something and my icons appear.

How can I make this refresh programmatically? Preferably without admin privileges.

I tried `update-desktop-database`. At least for unprivileged user this didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got the answer from Sparhawk:

```
kbuildsycoca4
```

Comment: You can also try `xdg-desktop-menu forceupdate`.